# Why is the Enterprise XCV 330 not on the wall in Archer's ready room?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, uss-enterprise

As can be seen in the below image of Archer's ready room, there are four sketches of various ships bearing the name *Enterprise*:

[image: Archer's ready room]

Compare this, though, to to the below image seen on the *Enterprise* in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*:

[image: Ships named *Enterprise* on the *Enterprise* refit[[2]]

Now, the first three images in both pictures above are of the same ships.  Then we get into interesting territory.

The *Enterprise* NX-01 isn't shown in the picture aboard the *Enterprise* refit from *TMP*.  That's understandable out-of-universe, because *Enterprise* hadn't been made by the time they made *TMP*.

Yet, there is a ship between the Space Shuttle *Enterprise* and Star Trek's *USS Enterprise* on the *Enterprise* in *TMP*.  I've found out that this ship is the [*USS Enterprise* XCV 330](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28XCV_330%29) which, according to Memory Alpha, was in service **prior to 2143**, something established in *Enterprise*: 'First Flight'.  The series *Enterprise* starts in **2151** according to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/ENT).

So, it's made pretty clear that the XCV 330 existed prior to the NX-01.  We also know it was significant enough to be put on a display gallery on the refit *Enterprise* in *TMP*.

So, **why is the *Enterprise* XCV 330 not on the wall in Archer's ready room?**

Comment: Why should it be? They only had room for four and that one sticks out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @Kevin : That's basically my answer...but they could have chosen a different wall.  They do look their best on that particular wall. :-)

Comment: @Kevin see my comment below Praxis' answer - in fact, you could argue that the battleship sticks out like a sore thumb!

Comment: @TheDoc look at it visually. Ship, ship, ship, WTF IS THAT, ship.

Comment: I don't know But here's mine. :-) http://s377.photobucket.com/user/JGG1701/media/Measurements%20for%20XCV-330/XCV/XCV%20Completed%20001_zpsvh9y0e2b.jpg.html?sort=2&o=214

Comment: Archer resented Vulcans for a long time, and the *Enterprise* XCV 330 with its drive ring strongly resembles Vulcan ships.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## This wall ain't big enough for the five of us.

According to [Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/ship_walls.htm),

> **John Eaves created an additional fifth picture, of the aircraft carrier USS Enterprise CV-6, which didn't make it on the wall.** Overall, this "ship wall" looks like a very balanced and diverse selection of ships named Enterprise, a bit like already in "Star Trek: The Motion Picture" but with some retroactive continuity regarding the omission of the ring ship XCV 330, which is currently considered to be just a testbed for a new propulsion technology. **The appearance of the XCV 330 in the 602 Club in "First Flight" and in Admiral Forrest's office in "Home" proves that the design was not simply forgotten.**

To prove that the fifth painting exists, here it is:

[image]

The fact that Eaves had created a fifth painting shows that they weren't necessarily limiting themselves to the four that we see.  But it seems that when it came time to hang them in the Ready Room set, they chose that particular wall, which only fits four of the drawings.  Accordingly, the CV-6 drawing was set aside and there would have been no need to make an XCV 330 drawing.

In choosing four, they seemed to go for diversity over continuity, as the article observes.  Even if wall-space considerations weren't the deciding factor, the choices are well-balanced with **two sea vessels** and **two space vessels**.

Comment: Interesting they should choose the battleship rather than the XCV - all the others were exploring new frontiers other than the battleship (no disrespect to the battleship of course!)

Comment: @TheDoc : Archer was very much about the new technologies...perhaps more so than about new frontiers.  The wall works with that.

Comment: Good point actually!  Hadn't thought of it in that context

Comment: LOL! I can’t believe this is the answer..

Answer (score -1):

Technically,  the second picture is NOT the same ship.  Archer's screenshot shows the post-WWII nuclear powered aircraft carrier USS Enterprise CVN-65, whereas the second screenshot shows the famous WWII aircraft carrier hull number CV-6 as noted earlier.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do note however that the 'Your Answer' field should only be used when attempting to _answer_ the question, whereas this seems more like an attempt to _correct_ it. The proper way to post such a correction is by leaving a comment beneath the question, using the 'Add a comment' link. However, as a new user, you need to earn some more [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more.